# How to properly post a record in Rails testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to test that a creation of a new `Post` fails in my Rails forum app.

A `Post` should not be created when there is an empty title present.

I am trying this but it gives me bad URI Error:

```
Error:
PostsNewTest#test_make_a_new_post_with_invalid_title:
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com:80{:params=>{:post=>{:title=>"", :body=>"body", :user_id=>762146111, :category=>"general/announcements"}}}
    test/integration/posts_new_test.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <class:PostsNewTest>'
    test/integration/posts_new_test.rb:30:in `block in <class:PostsNewTest>'
```

Here is what I try, I fiddled a lot to get it work but I simply don't know how to do it properly. I would be pleased if someone could help me get it right:

```
  test 'make a new post with invalid title' do
    log_in_as(@user_archer)
    get new_post_path category: @valid_category
    assert_no_difference 'Post.count' do
      post  params: { post: {title:    @invalid_title,
                            body:     @valid_body,
                            user_id:  @valid_user_id ,
                            category: @valid_category}}
    end
  end
```

I dont get the route right where to post because it is not a named route like `post_a_Post_path`

Edit: Extra question does this belong into an Integration Test or should this be part of the Model Test for a `Post`?

Comment: Is this minitest? in rspec you definitely need a path, something like `post :new, params`

Comment: A post tests the action, not the model. The syntax depends on what you're using to test; you have no path here but one seems to be generated, so you'd need to check whatever you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have setup the routes according to the [Rails conventions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) (with `resources :posts`) you should create a post by send a POST request to `/posts`

You can inspect the actual route by running `$ rails routes`.

```
test 'make a new post with invalid title' do
  log_in_as(@user_archer)
  # this is not needed in an integration test
  # - get new_post_path category: @valid_category
  assert_no_difference 'Post.count' do
    post posts_path, params: { post: {
      title:    @invalid_title,
      body:     @valid_body,
      user_id:  @valid_user_id ,
      category: @valid_category}}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I figured that out too allready but I have a problem with your solution because the `category` parameter must be there because of the routing so when I dont do the line which you commented out it gives me a routing error. Can you provide in your answer where I should put `category: @valid_category` to make the routing work?

Comment: If you have a nested route you would call it as: `category_posts_path(@valid_category)`. Again I'm guessing you have set it up conventionally.

Comment: allright the scopes helped me alot. I now did it like this: `posts_path(category: @valid_category)`. Before that I just put it in front of `params:{...}` or behind. Now it works. Marked as the right answer. And yes I have put it conventionally but under a `locale` scope and this again under a `*category` dynamic wildcard scope